# Rails nested form - refactor create action | cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many, cocoon-gem

Everything is working fine but I want to change the code in **create** action to something like in **update** action. Right now, in the create action I am looping through all the values and saving them, but want to do it in a single line.

I have a College model.

```
class College< ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :staffs, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :staffs, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

And this is my Staff.rb

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :college
end
```

And these are my Staffs controller **create** and **update** actions

```
def create
  @college= College.find(params[:college][:id_college_profile]
  )
  staff_params = params[:college][:staffs_attributes].values
  staff_params.each do |staff_param|
    @staff = @college.staffs.new
    @staff.name = staff_param[:name]
    @staff.designation = staff_param[:designation]
    @staff.experience = staff_param[:experience]
    @staff.specialization = staff_param[:specialization]
    @staff.save
  end
  redirect_to dashboard_path(id: @college.id), notice: "Successfully added Staff."
end

def update
  @college= College.find(params[:college][:id_college]
  )
  @college.update_attributes(staff_parameters)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

These are strong parameters

```
def staff_parameters
  params.require(:college).permit(:id, staffs_attributes: [:id,  :name, :specialization, :experience, :designation, :_destroy])
end
```

**Is there a way to save all of staffs in create action, without looping through all the values, but save all of them with a single line of code as in update action?**

I have tried this in the StaffsController create action

```
def create
  @college= College.find(params[:college][:id_college]
  )
  @staff= @college.staffs.new(staff_parameters)
  @staff.save

  redirect_to dashboard_path(id: @college.id), notice: "Successfully added Staffs."
end
```

But it threw this error

```
unknown attribute 'staffs_attributes' for Staff.
```

Can someone kindly help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `CollegesController` so I am assuming the `create` action also creates the new college?

So in that case your create action should simply be something like:

```
def create
  @college = College.new(staff_parameters)
  if @college.save
    # succesfully created
  else
    # there was a validation error
  end
end
```

Note that in general we would use `college_parameters` because the root element is `college` and that you not only edit the nested staff, but also possibly attributes from college.

If the college always already exists (because you are doing a `find`), it is a bit confusing to me what the difference is between `create` and `update` and why not always render the `edit` action in that case?

I have a [demo-project](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo) show-casing cocoon and nested attributes.

Comment: Thanks for input. Here is the flow. User signs up. He is then redirected to a form. Upon submitting it, a college object is created for that user. This college object has staffs, courses, etc. 
So in staffs controller, I am creating staffs for that particular college. And the create action I posted is in StaffsController.

Comment: In that case there is no difference between the edit and new action, because you always render the form for college, and save the college, right? A bit confusing in your routes potentially, because you do not create or edit a single staff, but a bunch, so for me a college controller feels a little more "standard" resourceful.

Comment: Thank you @nathanvda. I am rendering the edit form for both new and edit now. I will move the code to the CollegesController. A small question. I also have 'courses' for colleges just like 'staffs'. If in colleges#create, I have `@college.update_attributes(staff_parameters)`, how to change the strong params so that it allows 'course_parameters' too when nested course form is edited.

Comment: If it is going to include the `courses`, I would start renaming it first (just `college_parameters` instead of `staffs_parameters` or `staffs_and_courses_parameters`), and then just add the `courses_attributes`. So something like: `params.require(:college).permit(:id, staffs_attributes: { ...}, courses_attributes: { .. })`. Pretty straightforward imho? Please check out the demo-project I shared for more elaborate/detailed examples.

Comment: Thankyou @nathanvda

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many ways.  The "staff_parameters" method threw an error because you are calling it on class Staff in the create action and on the college class for the update action.  Simplest thing to do what you want is to copy the staff parameters method strong parameters and duplicate it.  Name this second method create_staff and change the "params.require(:college)" part to "params.require(:staff)" and leave the rest the same.  Then in your create action you can do "college.staff(create_staff)".  Im on my phone so the formatting isnt good lol i put the code in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but there is an error. 

 `def create_staff   
     params.require(:staff).permit(staffs_attributes: [:id, :name, :specialization, :experience, :designation, :_destroy])
  end` 

This code is throwing this error `param is missing or the value is empty: staff`

Comment: Here are the params when I the form is submitted

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2JTUGSxkviYutVSkbmsNHfkAlHoxTOk70OPxsDTcyKlUKVFMJx5+xF9RU6sZiXwIQqfNmOpw1NqnjJzJtrTHXQ==", "college"=>{"staffs_attributes"=>{"1464614354720"=>{"name"=>"asdasd", "specialization"=>"asdasd", "designation"=>"asdasd", "experience"=>"12", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "id_college"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Save", "controller"=>"staffs", "action"=>"create"}`

Comment: In the create action,  I have this:  `@staff = @college.staffs.new(create_staff)`